# Python .plot sort by x axis

Tags: python

Ok, so I have this simple plot and wish for the displayed data to be shown in order 0 to 23 on the x-axis.

```
train_data['hour_of_day'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value_count() method will return a Pandas Serie object (with index and values ). So all you have to do is sorting this Serie with the index and then use matplotlib (for example) to plot (sorted_index, sorted_values )

for example i have this serie:

```
serie = iris.species.value_counts()
serie


versicolor    50
virginica     50
setosa        50
Name: species, dtype: int64
```

all i have to do is sorting it by index like this :

```
serie.sort_index(inplace=True)
serie 

setosa        50
versicolor    50
virginica     50
Name: species, dtype: int64
```

and then bar plotting the result

```
plt.bar(serie.index, serie.values)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!

g = train_data['hour_of_day'].value_counts().sort_index()

plt.bar(g.index, g)

This is what I did based on your response.

Comment: if it works , please make this answer resolved